# Dropdownlistfor Object reference not set to an instance of an object after the ModelState.IsValid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Having problem with `DropdownListFor` when it passes the (`ModelState.IsValid`). when it passes the `DropdownList`, the error (`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`) occurs

**VIEW**

Error in this line of the view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.si_g_code, new= SelectList(Model.Guardian,"g_ref_code","fullname"), "Select Guardian")
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.si_g_code)

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.si_gl_id, new SelectList(Model.GradeLevel,"gl_id","gl_name"), "Select Grade Level", new { id = "ddlGrade" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.si_gl_id)
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RegisterStudent()
    {
        Models.ModelActions action = new Models.ModelActions();
        var model = new acgs_qm.Models.CreateStudent
        {
            GradeLevel = action.getGrade(),
            Guardian = action.getGuardian(),
            si_id = action.getStudentNum()
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterStudent(CreateStudent Create)
    {
        acgs_qm.Models.ModelActions Ma = new acgs_qm.Models.ModelActions();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Ma.insertStudent(Create);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class CreateStudent
{
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Student ID")]
    public string si_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "First Name")]
    public string si_fname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Middle Name")]
    public string si_mname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string si_lname { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Contact Number")]
    public string si_contact_no { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Gender")]
    public string si_gender { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Civil Status")]
    public string si_civil_status { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Birthdate")]
    public string si_birthdate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Birth Place")]
    public string si_brith_place { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Guardian")]
    public string si_g_code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Enrolled")]
    public string si_enrolled { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Email")]
    public string si_email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Grade Level")]
    public int si_gl_id { get; set; } //fk
    [Required]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Section")]
    public int si_sec_id { get; set; } //fk

    public IEnumerable<GradeLevel> GradeLevel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Guardian> Guardian { get; set; }
}

public class GradeLevel
{
    public string gl_id { get; set; }
    public string gl_roman_no { get; set; }
    public string gl_name { get; set; }
}


public class Guardian
{
    public string g_ref_code { get; set; }
    public string g_fname { get; set; }
    public string g_mname { get; set; }
    public string g_lname { get; set; }
    public string g_contact { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
}
```

Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` equals to `false`, so it goes to `return View()`, but you don't pass necessary data like that you wrote inside the `RegisterStudent` *GET* method! you must pass again perhaps by using `return View(Create);` instead of `return View();` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.si_gl_id, new SelectList(Model.GradeLevel,"gl_id","gl_name"), "Select Grade Level", new { id = "ddlGrade" })
```

The `SelectList` takes Model.GradeLevel as parameter which is null
So you have to change the code like this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterStudent(CreateStudent Create)
    {
        acgs_qm.Models.ModelActions Ma = new acgs_qm.Models.ModelActions();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Ma.insertStudent(Create);
        }

        //Populate the values so that they wont be null in selectlist
        Create.GradeLevel = action.getGrade();
        Create.Guardian = action.getGuardian();

        return View(Create);
    }
```

Since in your view if dropdownlist is not selected then the model field will be null. So while passing to view in post method explicitly assign these values because always the dropdownlist needs the value.
Only if the model is passed to view,the object reference is set. Here in this code, when you are passing the Create to the view the reference of the model object is set to the instance of the Create object. 
This works for sure I checked. Wherever there is `Selectlist` you have to make sure the value passed is not null. For that purpose only i am populating

`GradeLevel` and `Guardian`

Answer (score 0):

**Http is stateless**. That means it will not keep your data between your 2 requests.

In your `GET` action method, you are loading data for the dropdowns and sending to the view. But in your `HttpPost` action method, When `ModelState.IsValid` is false, you are returning the same view. But you are not passing any model/viewmodel to that which has data for your dropdowns. Your razor view is trying to use the GradeLevel and Guardian collection to render the dropdown ,but since we did not load the data for those properties, it is **NULL**. That is the reason you are getting this error.

What you should do is, before returning the view, reload the `GradeLevel` and `Guardian` property values again.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterStudent(CreateStudent Create)
{
    var Ma = new acgs_qm.Models.ModelActions();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Ma.insertStudent(Create);
    }
    //Reload the data 
    Create.GradeLevel = action.getGrade(),
    Create.Guardian = action.getGuardian(),

    return View(Create);
}
```